# Identifier, GUID or "*" expected at position 126. Error when clicked on sitecore items under "Home"

Tags: sitecore-client

I am using sitecore 9.0.1 .For customizing search functionality i have created a VS solution where it was asked for a patch file configuration so i have added the below lines of code under "App_Config/Include/zz.project" folder and changed the sitecore "layers.config" custom path.

[image]

After adding this patch file my sitecore instance was up and i tried to modify the sitecore items which is created under HOME node the below error is showing up.
[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Undo your change to the layers config. You (probably) don't need it and it guess it broke your site.

Comment: I have kept Connectiostring.config fie and Patch file under /App_config/Include folder .I tried doing it but if i do that i will get a error saying that " Cannot read patch file 'ConnectionStrings.config'. <sitecore> node is missing. " It will not find my patch config file.@Gatogordo

Comment: Your connectionstring config should not be a patch file inside the include folder. Put that in your app_config.